# Switch statement not going through all cases - Javascript PT to html convertor

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So I'm trying to create a script converter that turns plain text into HTML. The whole idea is that there are two text boxes one has the user input and the other one is the output. I'm trying to use a switch statement to do this but for some reason, the switch only goes to the first case and not the rest. So it outputs `<br />` in the right locations but does nothing for the other cases. But from my understanding, it should go through every case in the switch.

(Side note I created this script in python using a whole lot of if/else statement)

```
<script>
  var btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
  btn.addEventListener('click', converter);

  function converter(){
    var text = document.querySelector('.in_txt').value;
    var text_input = text.trim();
    var output_html='';
    var counter;
    var hey = 0;

    if(text_input.length > 0){
      output_html+='<p>'; //begin by creating paragraph
      for(counter=0; counter < text_input.length; counter++){
        switch (text_input[counter]){
          case '\n':
            output_html+='\n<br>';      
            break;

          case ' ':
            output_html+=' ';                                                   
            break;

          case '\t':
              output_html+=' ';
              break;

          case 'FIRSTNAME':
              output_html+='{% if cons.firstname %}{{cons.firstname}}{% else %}{% endif %}';
              break;

          case '—':
            if(text_input[counter-1] != '—')
              output_html+='&mdash;';
            break;

          case ' - ':
            if(text_input[counter-1] != ' - ')
              output_html+='&mdash;';
            break;

          case '[image]':
            if(text_input[counter-1] != '[image]')
              output_html+='<table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">\n\t<tbody>\n\t\t<tr align="center">\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t\t<center>\n\t\t\t\t\t<a href="link"> <img border="0" style="display: block; margin: 0  auto; height: auto; width: 100%; min-width: 300px; max-width: 560px;" src="image" alt="alt"></a>\n\t\t\t\t</center>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t</tbody>\n</table>\n';
            break;

          case '\n':
            if(text_input[counter-1] != '\n')
              output_html+='<br />';
            break;              

          default:
            output_html+=text_input[counter];

        }  
      }
      output_html+='</p>'; //finally close paragraph
      }
    document.querySelector('.out_html').value = output_html; // display output html 
  }


</script>
```

Comment: why do you have two '\n' cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text_input[counter] always stores a single character, like 'a', ' ' or a new line char ('\n'), so it will never be equals "FIRSTNAME", ""[image]" as well as any other string with more than one character.
Because of thar your conditions that contains more tha one char will never be satsfacted in the code above.

Comment: This is correct I ended up using split instead of trim to get each word and I also replaced the spaces with  `<br />` before splitting into a new array.

`var newtext = text.split('\n\n').join('\n<br /><br />\n');
    var text_input = newtext.split(' ');`